# Fluent NHibernate OpenSession does not open new session

Tags: c#, oracle, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using Fluent nHibernate and Oracle database. I's working fine, but there is one problem, that i can't figure out.

I'm trying to create new session, after previos has been killed. But there is no new session in session list in pl/sql developer and query in second session throw exception like in first one. So my question is what i'm doing wrong or what i'm missing.

```
public static class FluentNHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                var dbConfig = OracleDataClientConfiguration.Oracle10
                  .ConnectionString(c => c.Is(RmsConnection.ConnectionString))
                  .ShowSql()
                  .FormatSql()
                  .Driver<OracleDataClientDriver>();

                _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(dbConfig)
                    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<RmsDu.Data.Model.MessageHead>())
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Open new db session 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
```

}

```
    [Test]
    public void SessionKillTest()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var session = FluentNHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                var q = session.Query<Data.Model.MessageType>();
                //Here we kill first session
                q.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}

        using (var session = FluentNHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            var q = session .Query<Data.Model.MessageType>();
            q.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: most probably the initialisation of the sessionfactory throws so every OpenSession() throws as well. the Stacktrace definitly would help

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that you have to dispose session.Connection manually before session dispose